Unable to Access Salesforce Due to Internal Server Error - Error ID: 1219203209-1325799 (1979267137)
We are experiencing an internal server error that is preventing multiple users from accessing Salesforce. Below are the details of the error:
Error Message: "An internal server error has occurred. An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem."
Error ID: 1219203209-1325799 (1979267137)
URL: https://d90000000zsmceau.my.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp
Issue Description:
Several users are unable to log in to Salesforce due to this error.
I have attempted to log in as an admin on their behalf, but I encounter the same error.
Steps Taken:
Verified user permissions, which appear to be in order.
Reviewed the Salesforce Status page, and there are no ongoing incidents affecting our instance.
I would appreciate your guidance on the following:
Steps to diagnose and resolve this internal server error.
Any known issues or common causes related to the provided error ID.
Recommendations on any additional information or logs that I should provide to assist in troubleshooting.
Thank you for your assistance in resolving this matter. Please let me know if you require any further information.

This question is similar to: Internal Server Error - What's in a GACK?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

We can't help you with this problem, as a GACK's internal details can only be seen by salesforce.com employees.  However, a search engine result led me to this feed over on the Trailblazer Community. There's no "accepted answer," but the comments suggest that it may be due to the profile being corrupted somehow. Try creating a new profile, assign a user to that profile, and see if they can then log in. Otherwise, your next step should be to contact Salesforce Support through whatever channels you have access to. They can help identify the cause of the problem.

I can see this is a global issue that started today. Please reach out to Salesforce support and check trust.salesforce.com for any issues reported for the same.
Regards
